# high number of bytes read from write queue

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor, gem5

If you see a high number of reads from write queue for a program, what would you guess about that programs behavior?

I have noticed for majority of programs there are very few bytes read in total from the write queue but this is not true for one case which I'm studying. I'm trying to explain that.

I'm using gem5 for my simulations btw.

Answer (score 1):

You mean store-forwarding?  That probably means the program has a lot of store/reload.

e.g. from passing args on the stack, and/or by reference so the caller has to store and the callee has to reload (if the function doesn't inline).

If you're simulating x86, even call/ret can reload the return address from the store buffer.